# Nasm, Can I directly exchange memory data in one line?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to use nasm to compile my program, and I met a problem about nasm syntax.
Actually I am writing this code:

```
mov byte [edi],[esi]
```

nasm just gives me an error, says

> invalid combination of opcode and operands.

So I want to ask whether I can directly exchange memory data in one line without using other register as media.

Comment: In general, no. But in that specific case you can use the `movsb` instruction. Refer to volume 2 of  Intel's manuals.

Comment: @Michael I try it, but it fails again. Does this use nasm to compile it?

Comment: _"it fails"_ is not a sufficient problem description. What is the _exact_ error message you're getting, and what is the _exact_ line of code that the error corresponds to?

Comment: @Michael This is error message:"error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: You can't exchange two items in memory without using a register. There is no way to do it. There is the xchg instruction that can exchange a register with either something in memory or another register, but there is no way to exchange what is stored in two memory locations without using a register or a third memory location.

Comment: Like I said: What is the _exact_ error message you're getting, **and what is the _exact_ line of code that the error corresponds to**?

Comment: @Michael if I change code into movsb byte [edi],[esi], it says "error: invalid combination of opcode and operands". maybe nasm doesn't support this operation

Comment: Are you trying to swap/exchange the byte values in two memory locations or are you just trying to move/copy the byte from one memory location to another?

Comment: _"maybe nasm doesn't support this operation"_ It certainly does. But it should be `movsb` with no operands.

Comment: [MOVSB](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) would work as a copy from one memory locaiton to another, but depending on the direction flag (set or cleared with STD/CLD) the _ESI_ and _EDI_ will both be incremented or decremented during that operation.

Comment: Look at the Intel insn ref manual.  See the links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: @Michael I see, thank you.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction format you are using is "illegal". There processor does not understand moving between two memory locations. That is why you are receiving an error. By using the direct register addressing mode (using the square brackets) you are giving it memory addresses stored in each of the registers listed (edi, esi).

The processor simply cannot do that. I'm sorry. You are going to have to find a different way to do what you're trying to do.

Now, the movsb instruction will move one byte from the address pointed at by esi into the address pointed at by edi. That may be what you are trying to find, but in that case the code is simply

```
movsb
```

with no parameters. It will also increment or decrement esi and edi depending on the value of the direction flag (which is normally clear so it would increment).

You can use the rep modifier to repeat the instruction the number of times indicated by the value stored in ecx.

Remember, the values IN edi and esi will be changed by the movsb instruction. If you use movsB, they will be incremented or decremented by one.

If you need to exchange two values in memory, you can do it with one additional register as pointed out by another user in response to my slightly less efficient method with two registers:

```
mov edx, [edi]
xchg edx, [esi]
mov [edi], edx
```

This will swap the contents of the memory addresses pointed at by the contents of `edi` and `esi`. There's no shorter way to do it.

Comment: Technically there is a shorter method: `mov edx, [edi] / xchg edx, [esi] / mov [edi], edx`. It saves 4 bytes, but may run slower.

Comment: @owacoder, that makes sense - I edited out my original answer after I remembered the movsb instruction, but your answer is shorter than my original answer.

Comment: If the direction flag is clear ([_CLD_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CLD.html)) it is forward/incremented, and if set ([_STD_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STD.html)) it is backwards/decremented

Comment: Good catch, @MichaelPetch. I _meant_ that the flag's value is normally such that it it would go forward. Poor choice of words on my part.

Comment: Your present answer doesn't deal with truly exchanging anymore. Since the OP didn't bother to clearly say what he wants, I think you should re-include your code to exchange memory (or the smaller version presented by @owacoder), keeping of course all the rest about `movs`.